# Unhandled Alert Exception : Modal Dialog Present (Selenium)

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, selenium

I am facing an Issue wherein I get an Exception saying UnhandledAlertException Modal Dialog Present ,below are some of the traces

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present:
>   This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you
>   have entered may not be saved.Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision:
>   '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27
>   11:29:39'System info: host: 'NCESEPBLRNRE16', ip: '172.16.137.213',
>   os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1',
>   java.version: '1.6.0_26'Session ID:
>   bda22089-a586-4cd8-b7ac-778c98581e11Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriverCapabilities [{platform=XP,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=23.0,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true}] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createUnhandledAlertException(ErrorHandler.java:174)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:141)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:389)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214) at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
>   at
>   com.amadeus.selenium.runner.SEPWebDriverWrapper.findElement(SEPWebDriverWrapper.java:141)

I searched for some solutions and got the following snippet to handled the issue

> //Now the alert appears.  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
>   alert.accept();

It works fine , but the alert popup appears in different instances (or different scenarios ) for which the alert cannot be handled in all blocks of code

Please let me know if there is any common approach wherein i can disable this alert popup permanently through some firefox profile settings or anyother generic approaches

I am using Selenium Java with browser as Firefox

Comment: I will advise handling alerts as per the expected behavior instead of disabling them everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but the issue is occurence of  AlertPopup is not at the same instance all the time , tats y i thought of any settings wherein firefoxprofile to disable it permanently aslike the download window popup

Comment: Surely you know when the alert will appear and when it won't? This is your site, right? You know what the application actually does, right?

Comment: I have the seen the alert popup occuring in different scenario , although i am able to handle the alert in one instance using              **Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept();** . So just to make sure that it doesn't appears in different scenarios , I feel it could be better if we permantley disable . Tats the reason i am asking for if there is anyway to permanently disable it

Comment: if you use a try/catch around the accept alert code you have and then don't do anything with the exception it would attempted to close the popup anywhere you need to, but if the popup isn't there your test won't error.  not the best practice, but depending on what you're going for it could work.

Answer (score 6):

Write a method like this:

```
protected boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Call the above method to verify whether alert is present or not as below:

```
if(isAlertPresent()){
            System.out.println(isAlertPresent());
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, but am still getting the `org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present`.

Comment: Where have you written 1st method (isAlertPresent() )? In the same class or in different class? If you write in same class please use private or public instead of protected.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using combination of Robot class and selenium Alert switch to command.

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
// invoke Robot class
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.KeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
rb.KeyPress(KeyRelease.VK_ENTER);
```

try this out and let me know if any issues. it worked for me because I have faced thi issue earlier.